# Rich Media Shares

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the API to upload images. It looks like they have an API to do this https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares.

From what I'm reading I need to apply for their partner program to get access to additional endpoints. It's not clear what program I need to apply to. I see mention of a "Consumers Solution" partnership but when I go to apply that isn't an option... https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply.

What program do I need to apply for to get access to get access to this API?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your using the API for. If you're using it for marketing solutions, than you want to fill out [this application](https://learning.linkedin.com/partners/partner-application#). If you're accessing the API for the sake of learning/teaching/education, you want to fill out [this form](https://learning.linkedin.com/partners/partner-application#). If you're trying to sell a product through LinkedIn, you want [this form](https://business.linkedin.com/sales-solutions/partners/become-a-partner). If you're trying to use the LinkedIn API to source talent, you want to fill out [this form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR9NGaraHZBFMnmu44oLEKp1UNEFBVU9YSFJFUE03RUU3UFU4MEJXRVRLRi4u).

If you don't have a specific use-case that falls into one of these categories, they probably won't grant you additional access even if you fill out the application.

Comment: We currently use the API to share links and content to LinkedIn personal profiles and company pages. We would like to add the ability to upload photos with the rich media endpoint. The learning, product selling and source talent applications don't make sense for us.

They have their consumer partnership but there doesn't seem to be an application for it... https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/consumer